A specific class of languages
We say a languages $L$ is permutable such that $x\in L$ if and only if a permutation of $x$ be in $L$. Does the set of permutable languages is context-free or not?
I think there is a permutable language isn't context-free:
Let $L={a^nb^nc^n}\cup c^nb^na^n$
obviously $L$ isn't context-free.

What is a permutation of a word?

Also, how could a set of languages be context-free? Context-free is a characteristic of languages, not set of languages.

Your proposed $L$ does not seem to be a "permutable" language. The string $aabbcc$ is in $L$, but not the string $abcabc$, despite it being a permutation.

@ZiadIsmailiAlaoui If I understand OP correctly, then $L$ is permutable if $x \in L \iff \exists x' \text{ permutation of } x \text{ s.t. } x' \in L$, not that neccessarily all permutations of $x$ must be in $L$.
Using this definition OPs language would be permutable, but so would be any language since any $x$ is trivially a permuation of itself.

@Knogger Your interpretation would indeed explain the example given in the question. I read this as: The string $x$ must be in $L$ iff any of its permutations $x'$ is in $L$. Then all permutations are in $L$. The alternative would be: For all $x \in L$ there exists a permutation $\dots$. (Person shrugging emoji).

Your proposal is not yet closed under permutations. What you intend is probably the language $\{ w\in\{a,b,c\}^* \mid \#_aw = \#_bw = \#_cw\}$, where the $a,b,c$ can be in any order.
A different approach is to consider a restricted alphabet. What about $L\subseteq \{a\}^*$?
